# Possible to use if/else statements for $scope.$watch?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm playing around with Angular and trying to see if the above is possible.

```xml
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input ng-model="name">
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>
    <h1>{{age}}</h1>
</div>
```

```js
var Ctrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "Kevin"
    $scope.age = "26"

    $scope.$watch('name', function() {
        if($scope.name = 'Bob') {
            $scope.age = '101';
        };
    });
};
```

However, doing this just sets the value of `name` to "Bob" instead of "Kevin".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `==` instead of `=` in this line:  `if($scope.name = 'Bob') {`
:)

Answer (score 2):

here is what you are looking for try this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1GY4aCd2xa1LOZU9QmSQ?p=preview)

```
   $scope.$watch('name', function(newval,old) {
 //  alert(old + newval)
if (newval == 'Kevin') {
  $scope.age = 99;
} else if (newval == 'Bob') {
  $scope.age = 101;
}
```

})

Try changing the input value from Kevin to Bob and vice versa for change

Answer (score 1):

Callback inside `watch` function should take parameter like this:

```
$scope.$watch('name', function(newName) {
  if (newName == 'Kevin') {
    $scope.age = 99;
  } else if (newName == 'Bob') {
    $scope.age = 101;
  }
})
```

Here's plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kTOXrSfRTXE7HCUsZfh2?p=preview

Changing `$scope.name` between 'Bob' and 'Kevin' affects `$scope.age`